# How could I get the RAW pixel data out of a .NEF file using python?

Tags: python, image, camera, python-imaging-library, photo

I'm writing some scripts in python that manipulate raw camera data. At the moment I'm using DCRAW to convert the information from the .nef (Nikon RAW format) file to a .tiff file and then converting it to an sRGB .png in photoshop so that I can use Pillow to read the pixel intensities.

Is there a way to parse the .nef file itself in python, instead of jumping through so many hoops?

I'm not concerned with speed, this is mostly a learning and demonstration exercise.

Answer (score 11):

You might be able to make use of another library in combination with Pillow to achieve this task. For instance, `rawpy` could do the job for you.

Their examples at the following link show how to read `.nef` files and convert them to `numpy arrays` using the `postprocess()` method. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rawpy/0.3.5

From there you can easily save the images as TIFF or maybe do something like.

```
from PIL import Image
new_img = Image.fromarray(numpy_array)
```

Edit: 
I wrote a little script using rawpy and pillow that takes a .nef image, converts it into a numpy array, creates a new pillow image out of it, and shows it on the screen (obviously you can read intensities instead of showing it on the screen)

```
import rawpy
from PIL import Image
raw = rawpy.imread('trial.nef')
rgb = raw.postprocess()
img = Image.fromarray(rgb) # Pillow image
img.show() # show on screen
```

Comment: Two excellent libraries: rawpy and imageio. Additionally, you could use python-gphoto2 or gphoto2-cffi for an acquisition and processing pipeline.

Comment: can some one compile a binary for python 3.5 on windows for this? I dont have vs 2015 to do it myself, and i could not find a binary for this...

Comment: when I try this, my output image looks wrong; I think maybe the colour channels are reordered or something as my image has a very noticeable red shift. Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Solved it:

rgb = raw.postprocess(rawpy.Params(use_camera_wb=True))